# Search Kit not working in Civicrm 5.52.0

Tags: wordpress, searchkit, formbuilder

Civicrm 5.52.0  Wordpress 6.0.1 PHP version 7.4.30

Last week I upgraded to 5.52.0 which has been working fine, that is until today when I tried to take a look at Search Kit and Form Builder which are both installed and had been working OK.  When selecting SearchKit from Search/Search Kit, I'm getting a message " Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.Entity not loadedSearchSegment" and also "Error: Entity not loadedSearchSegment".

Can anyone please tell me if there have been any regressions and should I update to 5.52.2?

Comment: I think there was an issue that earlier civicrm had the searchkit extension as a contrib, now it is a core, so you have to disable/remove the old searchkit, and reinstall, but my quick search for answer isn't finding a helpful link. you may find an answer now with a bit more info (hope i am not getting my wires crossed with another extension) - do not apply my suggestion without a second opinion. if i find link later i will come bac and add.

Comment: ah. think it may have been more to do with FormBuilder https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3036

Answer (score 3):

I'm pleased to say that upgrading to CiviCRM 5.52.2 seems to have cured my problem and SearchKit has reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you need to perform database upgrade upon visiting the extension page?

Comment: Hi Pradeep.  Thanks for trying to help.  My extension page doesn't show any requirement to update database.  Both SearchKit and Form Builder are enabled showing version 5.48.2  If both are now in core, am I advised to disable and uninstall both extensions before perhaps updating to 5.52.2?